# Remote Logman with Credentials

Tags: performance, remote-access, remoting

I am trying to use logman on remote machines and have run into a couple of issues.

The first issue is as follows.  I am trying to use logman to tell a remote machine to create a performance counter.  I use "logman create  -s  -u  ."  This fails with access denied.  If I run on that remote machine with "logman create  -u  " then it works without issue.  I am guessing there is some network setting I am missing that will allow me to use the logman commands remotely.

The second issue is with the query and start commands.  The "u" argument for specifying a username and password is not allowed for reasons I do not understand.  If I try using the command "logman query  -s " then I will get access denied, but I have no way of passing user credentials since attempts at using the "u" argument gets be the message that "Argument 'u' is not allowed with the other arguments specified."

I am running the logman commands from Powershell, though I don't think that should make a difference.  If necessary I could use invoke-command to run these calls on the remote machine, but I'd rather avoid that if possible especially since logman is supposed to give me the option to run the commands on a remote machine and pass credentials already.  Does anyone know a way of solving these two issues?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar issue in the past.  It is network and windows access related.  If you can try this,  for user name and password use the same on both machines.  If that is not possible try qualifying the remote machine user name with the machine or domain name where the user exists.